# How can find the process that deleted my file

Tags: shell, unix, filesystems

I am using a unix based system.
I have a file that is being written to and read by several scripts, not all are in my control.
Every once in a while, the file disappears.
I cannot figure out which process/user/script is causing this. 
Is there a way to monitor a file in a way that I can later see which process has removed it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility such as `inotify` to observe the changes in the filesystem.

[IBM docs on using inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) does not indicate that it shows *who* did the deletion.  A tracing tool such as [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [`truss`](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?truss%201) (all system-dependent) can show process-ids and corresponding system calls (such as `unlink` or `remove`).

Answer (score 0):

If your system supports it, you can turn on C2 auditing.